# PySimpleGUI: _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!frame3.!entry"

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

I am trying to update a PySimpleGUI inputText field. This is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
layout=[
[sg.InputText('',key='-IN-')],
[sg.InputText('',readonly='true',key='-RESULT-')]
]
win=sg.Window('Test',layout)
while True:
    event,values=win.Read()
    win['-RESULT-'].update(win['-IN-'].get())
```

But i get an error like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 9, in <module>
    win['-RESULT-'].update(win['-IN-'].get())
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 1666, in update
    self.TKEntry.icursor(tk.END)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3057, in icursor
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'icursor', index)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!frame2.!entry"
```

Comment: Are you using tkinter along with PySimpleGUI?

Comment: Yes Im using PySimpleGUI and PySimpleGUI uses tkinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find there's only one event which is close button of window clicked.
After close button of window clicked, window will be destroyed and you can do nothing about the window, so you need to check if window closed and break from while loop to close window.

You can set option `enable_events=True` of `sg.Input` to enable event generated when input.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.InputText('', enable_events=True, key='-IN-')],
    [sg.InputText('', readonly=True, key='-RESULT-')]
]
win = sg.Window('Test',layout)

while True:

    event, values = win.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-IN-':
        # win['-RESULT-'].update(win['-IN-'].get())
        text = values['-IN-']
        win['-RESULT-'].update(text)

win.close()
```

Comment: Yay i used event and it worked! I didnt have to use values[-IN-],  i used window['-IN-'].get() and that was fine. Thanks again, now i made my own octal to number calculator which automatically updates result.